# .NET 6 Opentelemetry HTTP metrics

Tags: asp.net-core, open-telemetry

I have an application running in .NET6 and I would like to integrate it with OpenTelemetry for metrics gathering.

Documentation I'm following is: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore/README.md

Code that I have implemented:

```
services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithMetrics(builder => builder
        .AddOtlpExporter(o => { // ...})
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        ...
```

However I do not see the proper http-metrics being instrumented. In the documentation it also mentions that from .NET8 that it will automatically enable built-in metrics.

So my question is: how can I instrument http metrics in .NET6 using OpenTelemetry (something I'm doing wrong?), or will the auto instrumentation only work after upgrading my application to .NET8?

PS: Trace instrumentation is working fine.

Comment: Whether your application is a Web application (MVC, Razor Page or Blazor application) or a GRPC application? Which version of OpenTelemetry package you are using? Since this issue relate OpenTelemetry, you'd better to ask for help from the [opentelemetry-dotnet forum](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues).

Comment: It is a GRPC application with version OpenTelemetry version 1.5.1